# R: How to downsample a tibble with daily data to weekly Mondays data?

Tags: r, time-series

In Python using Pandas, you can do it with df.resample('W-MON').ffill(). What is the equivalent in R?

So far I have this, but it resamples using end-of-week data, and the code already doesn't look very readable:

```
downsample_weekly <- function(tbl, DATE) {
  ds_ts <- xts(tbl, order.by = as.POSIXct(tbl$DATE))
  as_tibble(ds_ts[endpoints(ds_ts, "weeks")])
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "downsample with daily data to weekly Mondays data"? I don't understand what you want as the result of your analysis.

Comment: I don't have a ton of experience in pandas, but `pd.resample` lets you summarize by a function, such as `mean`. Is that a functionality you're trying to get here? Can you be more clear about what you want, such as a dataframe indexed to every Monday with a value that's the mean of that week's values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to extract rows of a tibble corresponding to Mondays in some data field?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Example data
foo <- data_frame(Date = seq(ymd("2018-01-01"), ymd("2018-01-31"), length.out = 31),
                  Bar = runif(31))

foo %>% 
  filter(weekdays(Date) == "Monday")

#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   Date         Bar
#>   <date>     <dbl>
#> 1 2018-01-01 0.865
#> 2 2018-01-08 0.119
#> 3 2018-01-15 0.778
#> 4 2018-01-22 0.440
#> 5 2018-01-29 0.550
```

It isn't clear why your code used `xts`.